# How to say something is "annoying" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario, adjetivos, sustantivos

I have been wondering how to say **annoying**, *adjective* and *verb*, in Spanish (**ES**).  I come from the Northwest of the US and we use this word very often.
I have seen examples using *molestar* but none of them seem to be saying what I am trying to express.

For example:

> These mosquitos are very **annoying**.
>   OMG!  I can't believe how **annoying** Becky's voice is!
>   Stop **annoying** me! Stop! Stop!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The word would be "**molesto(a)**" which is an adjective. As a verb it would be "**molestar**"

With your examples would be like so:

> These mosquitos are very annoying. / Estos mosquitos son muy **molestos**.
>   OMG! I can't believe how annoying Becky's voice is! / ¡Dios mio! No
>   puedo creer lo **molesta** que es la voz de Becky.
>   Stop annoying me! / ¡Deja de **molestarme**!

Comment: also "irritante"

Comment: @Laura: Of course "irritante" could be used and it is correct but I do not think it is the best choice for this context for two reasons. IMHO "irritante" is something that is much more intense than annoying, something that I cannot stand anymore. Also, even though it is correct to say "Deja de irritarme" for "Stop annoying me" sounds funny and people (particularly teenagers) could make fun of whoever says that instead of stopping whatever they are doing.

Comment: for me depends on the context, foor example I would never say "una voz molesta" I would prefer "Una voz irritante" for the other cases, of course, "molesto" is usually better.

Comment: Hm, *mosquear* comes to mind, given your example. :)

Comment: I've heard people complain using `¡Cómo enfadas! meaning something like `How annoying!`

Comment: _Irritante_ is equivalent to _vexxing_. To vex is a lot stronger than to annoy. And having also the meaning of _distressing_ it covers the comments by Laura and Sergio Romero

Answer (score 4):

También se usa *enojar*.  Por ejemplo:  *No me enojes* significa 'don't annoy me'.

Comment: This could be added to the accepted question as a comment.

Comment: @JoulSauron: It's a distinct answer. It deserves its own chance at upvotes (both answers got mine_.

Comment: @TomAu I guess that's why we have "community wiki" option, to improve an answer given by different users.

Comment: Adjective: enojoso

Comment: I'd prefer "molesto" or "irritante": _This is annoying_: 'Esto es irritante'

Comment: At least in Mexico the correct phrasing would be "No me hagas enojar", which then is a completely different thing to "annoying"

Answer (score 4):

Molesto/molestar son los términos más habituales en Español de España. Si utilizas enojado/enojar en España te entenderán pero suenan demasiado formales (suenan a castellano antiguo). Tambien existen alternativas coloquiales - vulgares (muy utilizadas) como:

- 'dar la brasa'  = 'molestar'
- 'pesado/a' = 'molesto'
- 'plasta' (masculino y femenino) " = 'molesto'

"Juan es un pesado/plasta, no para de hablar", 
"¡Deja de darme la brasa, para de una vez!"

Answer (score 4):

You could go with `ser pesado` o `ser un incordio` o `ser un fastidio`

> Estos mosquitos son un incordio (alternativamente, Estos mosquitos no paran de **incordiar**)
>
> Estos mosquitos son un fastidio (estos mosquitos me están fastidiando).

`Fastidiar` is closer to `tease` in some contexts, but would work here.

`You are annoying me` or `Stop annoying me` can be translated with `incordiar` o `cabrear` (this latter one is closer to "you are upsetting me" or "you are driving me mad")

> Deja de incordiarme / Deja de cabrearme
>
> Me estás incordiando

For something like `Becky's voice is so annoying` you could use `molesto` or `cargante` (this latter one is similar to "pesado")

> Qué cargante eres con el temita, macho.
>
> Qué cargante es ese sonido.

Comment: You can simply say fastidioso, no?

Answer (score 0):

In Argentina is very common to say 'insoportable'.

> Los mosquitos son insoportables.

Comment: I have no idea why this was downvoted. Here in Peru, we also call annoying things “insoportable(s)” (e.g., “calor insoportable” = “annoying heat”), and reserve “molestoso” for annoying sentient beings (e.g., “niño molestoso” = “annoying kid”). “Molesto” is almost never used as an adjective, except possibly in formal situations.

Comment: im not the downvoter, but "insoportable" is way stronger than "annoying" as far as i know, in fact i don't think anybody would say "annoying heat", insoportable is more like unbearable.

Answer (score 0):

We would say fastidioso, like you’re annoying me, getting on my nerves but then again we’re raised southern and from Michoacán

Comment: I think this has already been suggested in a previous answer so this is more of a comment than an answer.